# Splitting a single large data set that contains two populations into two data sets

Tags: dataset, population, excel

I have a single data set that contains two populations(This is a fact.) The means are different. It's obvious when charting the data, but not obvious to me how to split them. Is there a method or methods to mathematically determine which sample belongs to which population? (I'm also having trouble googling search terms and keep coming back with a t-test)

Each sample contains 10 measurements.

Comment: here's a search term for you: clustering

Comment: @carlo Yes! Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at finite mixture models, though I am not sure you have enough data to apply this method.